# Got dlopen Error on Foundation - Kivy iOS

Tags: ios, audio, kivy, avfoundation

I'm trying to run my kivy app on my iPhone but the log shows this error:

```
Got dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 1): image not found
Got fallback dlopen error on Foundation: dlopen(/Groups/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/Current/Foundation, 1): image not found
```

After that the app is closed.

Running on the iPhone simulator the app shows the same error in debug log but run without problems. The exception occurs in SDL_coreaudio:

`NSString *category = AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Target->Build phases->AVFoundation.framework's status to 'Optional' then app should run if your app not using that framework.